# How to combine two lists to dataframe, where one of them will be my columns and another my values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had two lists

```
values = ['98', '42']
columns = ['PREC', 'TEMP']
```

I want to make something like this:

```
             PREC            TEMP
0            98               42
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3\* : Create a pandas dataframe from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800976/python3-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below would work where you pass the `values` to convert it to dataframe and then use the `columns` params to assign columns names and then you can override the `index` with your required index values in the `iteration`

```py
import pandas as pd
values = ['98', '42']
my_columns = ['PREC', 'TEMP']
my_index = '27/12/2021'

df = pd.DataFrame([values], columns=[my_columns])
df.rename(index={0:my_index},inplace=True)

           PREC    TEMP
27/12/2021  98      42
```

Comment: works! how can i set index?

Comment: Do you have specific index values ?

Comment: yep, I have one period

Comment: So you mean you want the index like - `["1.", "2.", "3.", .....]` and so on like that ?

Comment: for example
```
                              PREC                TEMP
27/12/2021               98                     42
```

Comment: it isn't a list

Comment: Oh period as in the dates ? so for each row you have required dates ?

Comment: yes, I will put this in for loop, because I'm treating a dict object and putting inside a list to make the dataframe

Comment: Its not best to build a dataframe in iteration. It defeats the whole purpose of optimization. Though I updated the code with index change at each iteration. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

values = ['98', '42']
columnss = ['PREC', 'TEMP']

df = pd.DataFrame([values])
df.columns =columnss
print(df)
```

output

```
 PREC TEMP
0   98   42
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this,

```
import pandas as pd

values = ['98', '42']
columns = ['PREC', 'TEMP']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns,values)),index=[0])
```

the output is,

```
  PREC TEMP
0   98   42
```